# Get all posts, regardless of status

Tags: plugins

I'm using the Sola Testimonial plug-in and there is a function that gets a count of all published posts.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=testimonials&posts_per_page=-1&status=publish');

$count = $my_query->post_count;

return intval( $count );
```

This function only returns posts that have a second parameter set to "Approved" ("Pending Approval" is the other option). I want to get a count of all "testimonial" posts, no matter what this parameter is.

I've tried

```
$count = $my_query->found_posts;
```

and

```
status=any
```

and

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=testimonials&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=any');
```

but it will only count posts that have the parameter set to Approved.

Any idea how to get a count of all "testimonial" posts, regardless of status?

Thank you!

Here's how the Approval Status appears in the edit bar (it's separate from Publish):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should write your request like this ("post_status" instead of "status"):

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=testimonials&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=any');
```

All [available post_statuses](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters) are:

Default value is 'publish', but if the user is logged in, 'private' is added.

Public custom statuses are also included by default. And if the query is run in an admin context (administration area or AJAX call), protected statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are 'future', 'draft' and 'pending'.

- 'publish' - a published post or page. 'pending' - post is pending review.
- 'draft' - a post in draft status.
- 'auto-draft' - a newly created post, with no content.
- 'future' - a post to publish in the future.
- 'private' - not visible to users who are not logged in.
- 'inherit' - a revision.
- 'trash' - post is in trashbin (available since Version 2.9).
- 'any' - retrieves any status
  except those from post statuses with 'exclude_from_search' set to
  true (i.e. trash and auto-draft).

You can specify several statuses in one request:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    array( 'post_status' => array( 'pending', 'draft', 'future' ) )
) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much @KAGG. I tried that and it's still returning the count for just the subset of 'testimonial' posts, not all of them. Many thanks!

Comment: It looks strange. I have added to the answer all available post types.

Comment: Thank you KAGG. Something strange is going on that we can't quite figure out. This should work but for some reason it's not. I appreciate your help!